# Redirect Chain Issue

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect all the traffic for every single page in my site

from **http://url.com** to **https://url.com**

from **http://www.url.com** to **https://url.com**

from **https://www.url.com** to **https://url.com**

So, I'm using this code into the .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But I'm having a Redirect Chain Issue, for example:

301
http://www.url.com/page.html → 
301
https://www.url.com/page.html → 
301
http://url.com/page.html → 
200
https://url.com/page.html

Any help to slve this redirect problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache

Comment: I think the problem should be in the structure. Building the site I clear the cache several times, so I don't think that is the problem. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by far the best code to solve the redirect problems.

**Redirect all http and all www. to https non www**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://url.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```